# Why click() method in jQuery behaves differently from DOM click method()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tired to simulate a click event on a child element in order to trigger its click event, and its parent element also has a click event on it.
At first, I believed that I could do this by either:

```
document.getElementById('child').click();
```

or in jquery

```
$('#child').click();
```

However, I later found that the two methods behave differently.

The dom's method fires click event as expected, but jquery's method fires parent element's click event for two times.

Here is an example on the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5t5jc7ey/

Could anyone explain why jquery fires two times for the click event of the parent element?

Comment: take a look on .triggerHandler("click") `http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/`

Comment: let me make the link clickable [.triggerHandler("click")](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

Comment: The root cause is `onclick` property on div tag. Remove it and add _jquery_ event handler `$('#parent').click()` and there won't be any problem.

Comment: I can only explain for me: jQuery triggered his event at first (we get "child" and "parent") but jQuery prevent the DOM event onClick on `#child` but not the trigger per se only the content of the function will not executed. This leads to trigger also and again the `#parent` onClick event. The next question is: It is a bug from jQuery or is it not other possible to handler?

Comment: @mukund It wroks, but I still can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

What I could conclude is that , The first click  of parent happens due to event bubling and the second time the parent triggers its own default click event   so it clicks again. so that default behaviour I am avoiding by using  `e.preventDefault();`

[**working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5t5jc7ey/1/)

see the code for more clear idea :

```
$('#jquery').click(function() {
  $('#child').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();}).click();
});

$('#dom').click(function() {
  document.getElementById('child').click();
});
```

> I will try to explain again:
>
> 1.The first click event of parent gets triggers due to event bubbling.
>
> 2. Second click event of parent is due to browser's default action which you can see by clicking on the div itself.  I am preventing
>      browser default action by using `e.preventDefault();`

And in output the parent click event you see in my fiddle is due to event bubbling. So it gives the required answer

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` only inhibits the default behavior, doesn't stop bubbling. use `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: This solves the problem, but I'm not sure I understand the explanation. And I think the point of this question was more for an understanding of the problem, rather than a quick fix.

Comment: @DBS you should read the api documentation: 

`event.preventDefault()` Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

`event.stopPropagation()` Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Comment: I updated the answer guys ,, i never said I am preventing the event bubbling

Comment: @SLowLoris The question doesn't ask to stop bubbling, this answer prevents the double event, not the bubble. I understand this topic, you're just not reading the question thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

If you place a breakpoint/debugger command in the parent click handler, you will see that.

The first one is from an event that looks something like this in Chrome:

```
j…y.Event {type: "click", timeStamp: 1467985074919, jQuery2240856213100863372: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: ""…}
    isTrigger : 3
    jQuery2240856213100863372 : true
    namespace : ""
    result : undefined
    rnamespace : null
    target : div#child
    timeStamp : 1467985074919
    type : "click"
    __proto__ : Object
```

This is the same event that we see in the child click handler if you do the same thing. This appears to be the jQuery "click" event bubbling up.

The second event looks like this.

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: false, screenX: 0, screenY: 0, clientX: 0, clientY: 0…}
    altKey : false
    bubbles : true
    button : 0
    buttons : 0
    cancelBubble : false
    cancelable : true
    ....
```

This appears to be a more traditional mouseclick that is targetted to the child and is in phase 3 (bubbling) to the parent.  These are the types of events you see when doing the non-jquery trigger.

My best guess is that this mouseevent is auto-magically generated by the browser as part of handling the jQuery event type=click on the child.

Sorry, not really a definitive "answer", but I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your trigger propagates to the parent elements. To prevent that you can use the
`event.stopPropagation()` method which stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Take this example:

HTML:

```
<p><a id="someId">Text</a></p>
```

JS:

```
$('p').click(function(event){
    something();
})
$('#someId').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    somethingElse();
})
```

In the above example, clicking the `#someId` link would trigger `something()` but not `somethingElse()`, due to the use of `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the parent fires twice.

Comment: "jquery's method fires parent element's click event for two times" Twice on the parent, once on the child, look at the example. Not twice total.

Comment: Notice that you can also examine the Event object and see whether or not it is "bubbling." It is certain that "bubbling" is the root cause of this behavior, because JQuery basically doesn't have the ability to "fire an event twice." It is *reacting* to what the browser sends it.

Comment: well maybe he's the one triggering it how about `$('p').click(function(e){e.target.trigger('click'});` for bubbling? code is incomplete, i'm just making an assumption here and i know i'm correct.

Comment: The code in his JSFiddle link is complete and correct, and it's reproducing the issue.